# What's best practice - either translate just the page title/meta description, or nothing at all?

Tags: seo, title, multilingual, meta-description, translation

I only have the translations for the page titles and meta descriptions. So I'm wondering, do I put the titles and meta descriptions in, keeping in mind that the rest of the page contents isn't translated.

It could be months before I have the rest of the site's content translated.

Edit: By "best practice", I mean which option would benefit seo ranking the most, and give users the best experience:

1. leave the whole page untranslated
2. include translated titles and meta descriptions

Comment: Could I assume that you mean that you want to translate your website into another language for the viewers?

Comment: Can you clarify as Nora asked if you plan on adding translated content in the future, but will have the same English content on the localized URLs till then, and would like to know if you should have their title and description translated in the meantime? If that's the case, I'd advise not to bother and instead add canonical links to the English URLs until you've translated the content, or just block them using a _robots.txt_ directive. After you get them localized, you can add an `hreflang` and upload an updated sitemap. See: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

Comment: Otherwise, the user experience (UX) would be poor and potentially dilute the sites performance. Even then, I am not sure how any search engine would handle this. High inadvisable. I would either translate the pages in full or not bother.

Comment: @NoraMcDougall-Collins Yes, that's the plan. Some pages are already fully translated. But for others, I've only got the title and meta and won't have the content translated for some time.

Comment: "Better" for "seo rankings" is not really the case here. If you offer translated pages, then those pages _may_ get indexed for that language, but how they rank is dependent solely on their content. Including just translated titles and descriptions will not do anything to help those pages get indexed, so "seo ranking" is a mute issue. As advised, this is a waste of time - either fully translate the pages, add canonical links, or don't post them at all.